# BigQuery table partitioning warning

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Recently when I tried mentioning table partition while creating a BQ table by using Python Client libraries with the below line,

```
table_new.partitioning_type = 'DAY'
```

Got the below warning,

```
UserWarning: This method will be deprecated in future versions. Please use Table.time_partitioning.type_ instead.   UserWarning)
```

Can someone explain this? If possible share a snippet of how to specify the partition type going forward.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are getting appears in the Python client libraries [[1]](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/table.html) when you use `Table.partitioning_type` in Python 3.

You can use the code expressed like this instead [[2]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/docs/bigquery/snippets.py#L625):

```
table_new.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY)
```

This code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.